# Is the correct term for the addition to Settlers of Catan that adds 5-6 player support, expansion or extension?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've always referred to the additions to Settlers of Catan that adds Settlers of Catan support as Extensions.  It's what's printed on the 4th edition box.  I've noticed though, [Catan and Seafarers 5-6 player expansion](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1726/catan-and-seafarers-5-6-player-expansion) that it was changed to call it an expansion.  I've corrected the text back in the post, but it's got me thinking.  What's the correct terminology for these additions?  Expansion or extension?

Also, are there any other games that add support for more players like Settlers of Catan, and how do they refer to these additions.

Comment: P.S. "4th edition box".  I don't have the rep to edit your post to fix this, though.

Comment: @Powerlord Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I've found [this discussion](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic48555.html) on the net. Although it defines the terms differently than I would have it does seem to fit the observed usages better.

> In a very general description, one might define these verbs as follows:
>
> - To extend = to increase or be increased in length or distance, in one dimension;
> - To expand = to increase or be increased in size, in two or more dimensions.

Unfortunately this definition is not very useful since we're dealing with a mostly metaphorical use.

Wikipedia however does not include any gaming related bullet point in under [Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension), where under [Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expansion) it does. Furthermore I've only ever heard the term "Expansion" used for additions to CCG's or Online Games.

I would thus conclude that the generally accepted term is **Expansion**...

Comment: I agree most games only call things expansions, but I'm curious if other people follow the exception to the norm Catan has their boxes labeled.

Comment: @ICodeForCoffee: Even Catan used to call them "5-6 Player Expansion."

Comment: @Powerlord So which form is correct for Catan now?

Comment: @ICodeForCoffee, my copies (old editions) all say expansion, my conclusion is bad translation, since you'd never use extension in an american description of a game, its always expansion.  I'm blown away that you edited it back.

Comment: @Lance Roberts.  I own the current American 4th addition of Catan.  It clearly says Extension on the box.  See for yourself:  http://boardgamegeek.com/image/268840/the-settlers-of-catan-5-6-player-extension

Comment: @ICodeForCoffee, I saw the box cover for the new one elsewhere, it's a shame they didn't get better translators for the new edition.

Comment: It's also called Extension on BoardGameGeek.  I was just going with what I thought was the standard on the edits.  You can change it back if you want.